# How to disable pretty urls in WordPress? I want my website's link to display mysite.com/about.php instead of mysite.com/about

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, custom-wordpress-pages

I made a beautiful website for my boss and told my boss that the site was built using WordPress.

Now my boss is mad at me for doing it in WordPress and wants the website to be redone in PHP instead.

I know WordPress is a PHP framework, but it is beyond my capability to make my boss understand this.

I have then decided to make my website look like a core PHP Website.

**I do not plan on telling this to my boss.**

One of the processes involves making the URLs have a `.php` extension at the end.

I found that WordPress implements "pretty URLs" and I need help in making changes to my `.htaccess` file so that my URLs look have a `.php` extension.

The version of my WordPress site is 4.8.4.

I am also disabling the `wp-admin` login so that it does not look like a WordPress website. Any other tips to make it look like a core PHP website are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in case you don't know: there are no php files that correspond to the pages in Wordpress (the only php files are the templates, but those have other names than the pages/posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to express that it is not a good idea to mislead your boss by simply changing the permalinks to include a `.php` extension. It is worth noting that even a website built with plain PHP can be configured to have pretty permalinks.

If you are intent on doing this, there are WordPress plugins that could possibly help you with this attempt. One such plugin is called `.php on Pages` and can be found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/dot-php-pages/

Comment: @mbaccon40 Thanks for your advice, I found a plugin which does the same thing, https://wordpress.org/plugins/append-extensions-on-pages/ and now it works with my wordpress version too :D